# how to use QJsonDocument to show the json in array

Tags: c++, json, qt

I have code for parse `json` response like this

```
QByteArray response_data = reply->readAll();
QJsonDocument json = QJsonDocument::fromJson(response_data);
qDebug()<< "json1: " << json;

QJsonDocument doc = QJsonDocument::fromJson(response_data);
QJsonObject obj1  = doc.object();
QJsonValue val1   = obj1.value(QString("Keys"));
QJsonObject obj2  = val1.toObject();
QJsonValue val2   = obj2.value(QString("Key"));
```

and the `json` response look like this

```
{
    "Keys":
    {
        "Key":
        {
            "ResultId":100,
            "Amount":0,
            "BPM":12,
        }
    }
}
```

when I use this code

```
qDebug() << "result ID: " << val2["ResultId"].toInt();
```

the output is `100` but when I want to use the `val2` like this not working

```
qDebug() << "FI" + val2["Amount"].toString() + "EY" + val2["BPM"].toString() + "EX"
```

the output is `json1: ""`

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you want to do here with `qDebug()<< "json1: " << json;`. Is the goal to read the object and then immediately print it?

The issue in the second part is that your types are not what you are converting to. All of the json objects here are 'int' types, and the documentation for `toString()` says "If type() is not String, a null QString will be returned.". `QVariant`, on the other hand, will convert to string representation even if it's holding a number. I suspect that if you do `val2["Amount"].toVariant().toString()` it will yield the result you want.

Comment: The JSON is not valid. Remove the comma at the end of the "BPM" line. Then I got it to work.

Comment: @Ipiano except, why bother going through `QVariant` at all, when the values are integers and `.toInt()` should be used to read them? Just like with `val2["ResultId"]`, eg: `qDebug() << "FI" << val2["Amount"].toInt() << "EY" << val2["BPM"].toInt() << "EX"`